# ¿Como puedo ordenar un listado a partir de un XML con XSL?

Tags: xml, xsl, xslt

Tengo el siguiente código XSL a transformar en HTML:

```
<xsl:template match="/">

        <xsl:output method="html" version="4.01" encoding="UTF-8"
            indent="yes" />

        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Ensenyament privat a Catalunya per comarques</h2>

                <table>

                    <tr>
                        <th>Comarca</th>
                        <th>Centres</th>
                        <th>Professors</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//comarca">
                    
                        <tr>
                    
                            <th style="text-align: left;">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@*" />
                            </th>
                            <th>
                            
                                <xsl:value-of
                                    select="centres/numero[@tipus='privat']" />
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <xsl:value-of
                                    select="professors/numero[@tipus='privat']" />
                            </th>
                        </tr>

                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>

            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

He utilizado la siguiente etiqueta para ordenar la tabla descendentemente de mayor número de "centres de tipo privado", pero hay algo que no estoy haciendo bien y no lo realiza.

```
  <xsl:sort select="centres/numero[@tipus='privat']" order="descending"/>
```

Este es el resultado que obtengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucionado**

No había tenido en cuenta lo siguiente:

```
 <xsl:sort select="centres/numero[@tipus='privat']"  data-type="number" />
```